# Swift iOS: custom keyboard only slightly different from default keyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, keyboard

For a word game, I want to create a UITextField programmatically in Swift that only allows users to enter and delete uppercase letters (no space bar, return, capitalization, etc). Like this:

[Desired Keyboard Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nXiv.png)

This doesn't appear to be one of the built-in keyboard options, but it seems like overkill to create a custom keyboard from scratch. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: How do you want your game to work for people using Chinese, Russian, Hebrew, etc. ? Or even languages such as Spanish that has extra letters beyond the basic A-Z such as ñ ?

Comment: I feel like a better approach would be to uppercase the string every time there's a keystroke without touching the keyboard at all. You can filter out the whitespace in the same callback, too

Answer (score 0):

Make a UILabel that looks like UITextField, this will help you to prevent system keyboard appearing. You can set text for the UILabel from your custom buttons. Try.

First make UILabel, add Tap gesture to it to handle click event.Let me know if the hint is not enough for you.

[Here](http://blog.oskoui-oskoui.com/?p=9141) . here you can learn how to make UILabel looks like UITextField